# Evaluate a double integral over a region $R$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $R$ be the refion enclosed by $x^2+4y^2\ge 1$ and $x^2+y^2\le 1$. Calculate $$\iint_R \lvert xy\rvert\,dxdy$$

I think the answer is $0$ because the area in the positive quadrants cuts the area in the negative. But I am not sure on how I should calculate it.

Comment: An integral of a positive continuous function is zero if and only if the integrand function is zero. This means that the integral is not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\iint_{R}|xy|\,dx\,dy=4\int_{1/2}^{1}y\,\int_{\sqrt{1-4y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}x\,dx=6\int_{1/2}^{1}y^3\,dy= \frac{45}{32}$$